# В чем разница преобразований?

Tags: c++

```
int a; 
a=int(3);
a=(int)3;
```

Чем отличаются данные преобразования?

Comment: Да по сути стилем написания... :)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast, но лучше использовать `static_cast`

Comment: то есть тут нет не только никаких принципиальных отличий,а от слова совсем?Зачем тогда в с++ надо было делать 1 способ?

Comment: @Whitehorse дело в конструкторах. int такой же тип как и любой другой (на самом деле нет, но это не важно), а значит и синтаксис создания экземляра должен быть такой же. Тобишь первый случай можно рассматривать как вызов конструктора типа int, а второй как преобразование, но по-факту это тоже самое

Answer (score 3):

По сути ничем, но сдесь стоит уточнить, что: первая запись валидна только для `c++`, в то время как вторая валидна как для `c++` так и для `c`